# Dart - Get result from a method invoked using reflection

Tags: dart, reflection, dart-mirrors

I'm trying to use dart's mirror API to dynamically invoke a function.

How can I obtain the result that's returned from the `doWork` method when invoking it via an `InstanceMirror`

```dart
class MyData {
  String someString;
}

class MyService {
  Future<MyData> doWork() async {
    print('doing work');
    return await Future(() => MyData()..someString = 'my result');
  }
}
void main() async {
  var instance = MyService();
  var mirrror = reflect(instance);
  var result = mirrror.invoke(#doWork, []);
}
```

I can see that `"doing work"` gets printed to the console so I know it's being invoked, but I'm struggling to interpret the result from the `invoke` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value are inside the `InstanceMirror` in the property `reflectee`. So something like this:

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

class MyData {
  String? someString;
}

class MyService {
  Future<MyData> doWork() async {
    print('doing work');
    return await Future(() => MyData()..someString = 'my result');
  }
}
void main() async {
  var instance = MyService();
  var mirrror = reflect(instance);
  var result = mirrror.invoke(#doWork, <dynamic>[]);
  var resultValue = await (result.reflectee as Future<MyData>);
  print(resultValue.someString); // my result
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was really struggling finding any docs to mention how to do this. Unrelated; why have you passed in the invoke params as `<dynamic>[]` in your answer - is this recommended over my approach, which was just passing an empty array?

Comment: @devklick I have some flags in my analyzer settings that prevents implicit `dynamic`. So if I want something to be `dynamic` I need to explicit write it. It is just so it is clear where `dynamic` can happen which means no static type checking. You can read more about how to make the analyzer more "strong" here: https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#enabling-additional-type-checks